# How to update table definitions for many tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server

We want to update our out-of-sync tables in our database to match a different sql server database instance.  We want to preserve the data in the database tables but will need to update contraints and column definitions.  What is the easiest technique for accomplishing this?

Comment: I'm not sure there is an easy way to do it.  Preserving the data through definition changes is problematic and in the general case, not  automatable.  Still, there may be some tool for the most common cases..

Comment: In your larger tables, how many rows are we talking about? How many schema changes?

Answer (score 0):

Brute force, but fairly easy to script would be to:

1. On the current data base (schemas you want), right-click on the DB and select *Tasks > Generate Scripts...*
2. Change the relevant parameters for what you need and save the script file (make sure you select the options to script all the indexes, triggers, etc.).
3. Create a fresh staging DB and run the script there.
4. Export all the data from the out-of-sync DB to the staging DB.
5. Drop all the tables on the out-of-sync DB.
6. Run the script on the out-of-sync DB.
7. Import all the data into the out-of-sync DB from the staging DB.
8. Delete the staging DB.

Obviously, you'll need to verify your data at the various steps before you go dropping tables or databases.